# Nuxt 3 page transition: can it be applied on page appear like Vue Transition component?

Tags: nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3, nuxt3

I'm devolping this Nuxt website with a simple page transition (fade in-fade out), and I'd like to play the animation on page load, like you do with Vue's Transition component with the "appear" parameter, but I don't know how (or if) it can be done.

I've tried adding "appear: true" to nuxt.config.js app.pageTransition attribute, but no effect.

Also tried encapsulating the NuxtPage component in App.vue in a Transition component but the transition wouldn't play, not even on page transitions. Same result when wrapping the  component in the default.vue layout.

Any hint is greatly appreciated :)